# MQTT client id in Haproxy

Tags: linux, haproxy, tcp

Is it possible to get client id in haproxy in tcp mode just like http mode.

I'm trying to get mqtt client id in haproxy tcp mode

Similar case in nginx:

https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-plus-iot-load-balancing-mqtt/